# MSBuild CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal Entity Framework Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, msbuild

I have a project which builds with MSBuild on my local machine but not on the build server.  I have installed visual studio onto the build server and the project builds fine on the build server.

I'm getting the following from MSBuild error: -

> error CS0012: The type
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject' is defined
>   in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to
>   assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0,...

The only difference I can find in the MSBuild output is the working build says _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal and my entity framework DLLs are copied across.  On the build which is failing that never appears.  I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and .Net 4.5, any help would be much appreciated.

The following is the section which never appears in the failing build.

> _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:   Copying file from "C:\CodeBase\DealerPortal\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll"
>   to "....\Assemblies\EntityFramework.dll".   Copying file from
>   "C:\CodeBase\DealerPortal\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll"
>   to "....\Assemblies\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll".   Copying file
>   from
>   "C:\CodeBase\DealerPortal\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\lib\net45\EntityFramework.xml"
>   to "....\Assemblies\EntityFramework.xml".   Copying file from
>   "C:\CodeBase\DealerPortal\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml"
>   to "....\Assemblies\EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml".

Answer (score 0):

The error basically says that msbuild cannot find System.Data.Entity.

If I understood your question correctly: msbuild works on your local machine, and building the project on the build server from within Visual Studio works.

The difference therefore could be the security context. When you run msbuild on your local machine you are running it as you. If msbuild runs on the server in the security context of a build agent, then the identity of the build agent could have problem accessing System.Data.Entity.

Another possibility is the location of System.Data.Entity, check how it is referenced.